# What word can fulfill the most parts of speech?

Tags: single-word-requests, parts-of-speech

I know there are several parts of speech:

- Noun
- Verb
- Pronoun
- Adjective
- Adverb
- Preposition
- Conjunction
- Interjection

There might be others as well.  Sometimes a word, depending on how it is used, can fulfill more than one of these classes. For example, the word "run" can be a verb:

> I run fast.

or it can be a noun:

> Let's go for a run!

What word, taking into account all its definitions, can fulfill the most word classes?

Comment: Not exactly addressing OP's "word class" issue, but I've always understood that in most English dictionaries the definitions for **set** occupy more pages than any other word. To be honest, I don't see much of interest in this "maximum word class applicability" shootout, especially with "pronouns" included in the possible classes. Does anything useable as a pronoun automatically get another point for also being a noun?

Comment: Just to be pedantic, rather than "word classes" you should say "parts of speech".

Comment: I'm pretty sure *fuck* can fit nearly all of those categories. It's quite an acrobatic word.

Comment: @ Jay:'Word classes' is now the more usual term among linguists.

Comment: @Barrie: Really? I guess I'm getting old. I'd never heard the term before. I thought the poster was just fumbling for a term.

Comment: Fast can be a noun, verb, adjective, or adverb.

Comment: @onoma...: Yes, obscenities are very versatile. They can mean pretty much anything, or nothing. Which is why they're pretty useless for conveying any information. They used to at least signal, "I'm very angry or upset", but now people use them so routinely that they don't even do that any more. Basically they're just filler.

Comment: @Jay I'm sorry they've lost their charm for you. They still do me quite well in many a situation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers **run** has overtaken **set** as the word with the most meaning in the OED. But I agree, this shootout seems unlikely to be a ["practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @onomatomaniak I once saw a skit by Playboy® about that word (and it's derivitives -ing, -off, -up...) It was the first thing that came to mind when I saw this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*[Well](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/well)* is an interjection, adjective, adverb, noun, and verb.  That's five.

> Business is going **well**. [adverb]
>   All is **well** with us. [adjective]
>   **Well**, who would have thought he could do it? [interjection]
>   The **well** was drilled fifty meters deep. [noun]
>   Tears **well** up in my eyes. [verb]

There's also *round*, with five, if you count when it is used to mean *around*:

> Give me a **round** figure. [adjective]
>   Shall we play another **round** of cards? [noun]
>   He had a look **round** before he kept going. [adverb]
>   They walked **round** the tree. [preposition]
>   The floor function **rounds** down. [verb]

Comment: What part of speech is it in the phrase "as well" / "as well as"?

Comment: The first is an idiomatic adverbial phrase as a whole, and the second is an adverb (cf. *as **quickly** as*, etc.), or else (when it means *also*) an indivisible idiom which can be either a [conjunction or a preposition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20well%20as) as a whole.

Comment: I wonder if using 'round' for 'around' is accepted usage, I think it's stretching things.

Comment: It is an accepted usage, listed in all major dictionaries I've looked it up in, as well as having been used much in speech and writing in my experience.

Comment: *Round* is fine, but *well* actually isn't, it's [two homonyms](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=well).

Answer (score 11):

**Damn** fits five of the categories.

-a verb: Damn you!

-a noun: I don't give a damn.

-an adjective: The damn rain won't stop.

-an adverb: That was damn close.

-an interjection: Damn! That was close.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155664/how-many-different-parts-of-speech-can-the-f-word-be-used-as. To me, 'damn' clearly matches all the claimed categories well, but 'f*' does not.

Answer (score 9):

The OED has definitions for *but* as 6 parts of speech: conjunction, preposition, adverb, noun, verb, adjective and pronoun.

- conjunction - "I would go to the store, **but** it's raining".
- preposition - "everything **but** the dog"
- adverb - "Bring **but** a bottle o' Primrose wine" (from OED) (synonymous with 'only')
- noun (archaic or Scots dialect) - "I found him settled in this **but** and ben." (OED) (inside of a house)
- verb - "Nay, **but** me no *buts*" (OED)
- adjective - "He conducted me to the **but** end of the mansion." (OED) (the very end)
- pronoun - "Not a man **but** felt the terror in his hair." (OED)  sort of a negative 'who'

Comment: OK, use *but* as an adjective for me.  Or as a pronoun. Or a verb.

Comment: Here's one of the OED's seven citations: 'Bring but a bottle o' Primrose wine.'

Comment: That's the adverbial usage.

Comment: You could stretch it. Adjective: "He just gave excuses: a bunch of 'but' answers." Verb: "He kept 'but'ing his answers." Preposition and adverb? I'd be hard pressed to even stretch that. But that's why this question could quickly descend into debates about how far you can stretch it.

Comment: Jay: Preposition and adverb are easy.  @Barrie just gave a adverb example, and here's a prepositional one: *No one replied **but** me*.

Comment: Oh, I'll concede the preposition. Now that you mention if, I can think of sentences like, "None but the brave would go there", or as the genii said in Arabian Nights, "None but I shall do him die."

Comment: I can only concede four of the parts of speech.  The other three have yet to prove themselves.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Here are more of the OED’s citations:

As an adjective: ‘He conducted me to the but end of the mansion.’ (but = outer)

As a pronoun: ‘Hardly one of the Frenchmen round, but . . . looked on Hereward as a barbarian Englishman.’ ('But' acts as a negative relative)

As a verb: ‘But me no buts.’

Comment: The rules for what is a word and what is the same word are taken with liberties here. I personally wouldn't consider the adjective 'but' here to be one of the uses of the 'but' we're thinking of (it is short for 'buttocks'). And 'but' as a verb means that -any- word can be used as a verb when quoted. The Scots noun seems to be another thing entirely. I feel that to be the 'same' word, there should be some etymological connection, and not just homophones.

Comment: Also, isn't the taxonomy of latinate parts of speech for English somewhat outdated and restrictive?

Comment: @Mitch: The OED's descriptions are based on evidence. For example, there is evidence for the use of 'but' as a verb. By contrast, I doubt if there is any evidence for the use of 'and' as a verb.

Moodern linguistics distinguishes between form and function, but terms such as verb, adjective and so on are still used to describe form.

Comment: @Barrie: in technical/logical circles, there are countless uses of 'and' and other logical connectives as verbs: "the procedure then 'and's the two conditions" (not particularly formal but it -is- used). Yes, this is tantamount to calling the OED loose or incomplete and/or capricious, but there it is.

Comment: @Mitch: You’re quite right. I should have checked first. The OED records ‘AND’ (in upper case) as ‘To combine (binary signals, search terms, etc.) using a Boolean and operator.’ The other main coordinator, ‘or’, is recorded as having a similar verbal use. It is true that anyone can use any word as a verb, especially by placing it between inverted commas. But dictionaries and grammar books can base their descriptions only on what is generally found in the language.

Answer (score 5):

How about the word ***down***?

- Noun: His pillow is made of *down*.
- Verb: The quarterback *downed* the ball.
- Preposition: He lives *down* the street.
- Adjective: His coat is made of *down* feathers.
- Adverb: He fell *down*.
- Interjection: *Down*, Fido!

Comment: Your interjection is really an imperative verb (or an adverb? depending on how you analyse it), so that's only five.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're just asking for amusement -- I don't see a practical application of an answer. Frankly, I think a question like this could quickly get bogged down in questions of definition and application.

Like, a candidate that occurs to me is "and", if I'm allowed to include the use of the word as a boolean operation, as in mathematics and computers:

conjunction (the obvious use): Bob walked AND talked.

adjective: We performed on AND operation on the two variables.

verb: We ANDed the two variables together.

noun: Put an AND in the expression here.

And of course almost any word can be used as an interjection: "AND! AND, you say! I would say BUT!"

Comment: Should your adjective one say "performed *an* and operation"?

Comment: Yes. That was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Both "buffalo" and "police" serve as enough different parts of speech to enable us to form entire sentences by simply repeating the word.

> Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo.

and

> Police police police police police police police police.

although these are basically just adjectives, verbs, and nouns.

**EDIT:**

These two sentences have identical structure (with some Buffalo capitalized because they refer to the city of Buffalo, NY). Below, the bold words are the subject and their action (buffalo from Buffalo, or "Buffalo buffalo"), the italics are another set of buffalo from Buffalo acting on those buffalo, and the plaintext is the buffalo being buffaloed (intimidated) by the original subject.

> **Buffalo buffalo** *Buffalo buffalo bufallo* **buffalo** Buffalo buffalo.

Or, more clearly,

> Bison from New York, who are intimidated by bison from New York, intimidate bison from New York.

I hope I've made it clear.

Note: In the "police" version, the structure is identical, but we are discussing "police police", or police that police other police, policing other police police while being policed by police police.

Comment: Can you explain these sentences...what they are conveying?  Graph them?

Comment: @JoelB expanded.

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice article [explaining this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo).

Comment: This is a great answer, although it does not attempt to answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

What part of speech a particular word in a particular sentence is often going to be a matter of dispute. This answer is probably valid according to some.

verb: Don't **her** me, I'm a guy.

noun: Is that a him or a **her**?

pronoun: Say hi to **her**.

[determiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner_%28linguistics%29): I see **her** car.

adjective: We got his and **her** towels. The his towel is on the rack, and the **her** towel is in the laundry.

interjection: **Her! Her!** Stop calling me him.

adverb: I passed **her** the salt.

Comment: Pronoun is a subset of noun, so you can remove one item. Determiner is a subset of adjective, so you can remove another. Your adverb example is not an adverb but a pronoun again (indirect object). Your verb is on the same shaky ground in which you can make -any- word a verb. And likewise your interjection, using any part of speech and quoting it, then saying it is pragmatically an interjection by exclaiming it.

Comment: @Mitch, I agree (to some of your objections, not all, but whatever; my point is...) Did you read the introduction to my answer?

Comment: In fact, the adjective example is also really quoting (the word woven into the towel, typically), and the determiner example is arguably a pronoun, which cuts it down to, at minimum, just noun. But, again, read my answer's intro: I posted what some would maintain are distinct parts of speech, not necessarily what you do, @Mitch.

Comment: Your pointing out that there might be arguable points doesn't preclude the need to spell out the arguments. Saying 'I disagree' or 'Others may dispute the following' is not an argument. If you can give justification (or counter arguments to my points) that would be very helpful. I claim there are only 2 instances, noun and adjective (as a direct or indirect object and as a possessive for the pronoun 'she'.

Comment: *'I passed **her** the salt'* is a pronoun (indirect object), not adverb. It's the same as *'I passed the salt to her'*, *'Say hi to her'*.

Comment: @smci, it's the same as _I passed the salt to her_, right. So it means the same as _to her_. Some will call that an adverb. Compare _I passed the salt northward_. See also the earlier comments on this answer.

Comment: *'(to) her/him'* is not an adverb, it's a personal pronoun (indirect object). Just like *'I gave him a kick'* - you would agree that use of 'him' is not an adverb, right? It doesn't matter if some people wrongly think it's an adverb, that doesn't make it an adverb.

Answer (score 2):

'like' can be up to **nine**! POS, props to [Ron Powell](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/18842/ron-powell) (he only claimed seven...).
Below as taxonomized by [Maggie Balistreri: "The Evasion-English Dictionary" (2003)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0971865973) + [essay on 'like'](http://blog.writeathome.com/index.php/2011/12/why-we-like-say-like-all-the-time/), or [Wikipedia on 'like'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like). See also 'whatever'.
Five of these are standard usage...

- **Verb** *'I like you'*
- **Noun** *'We will never see the like of him again'*
- **Adjective** *'using a like design to the iPhone'*
- **Preposition** *'He left early like his friend'*
- **Conjunction** *'Act like it's fun'*

...then there are these four colloquialisms, as taxonomized:

- **Adverb** *'They, like, hate you!'*
- **Interjection** *'I didn't say anything, like.'*  *'Like, get out of my way, biatch!'*
- **Quotative** *'I was like, "Who do they think they are?'*
- **Hedge (if you accept that)** *'I have, like, no money'*

Wikipedia: *non-traditional usage of the word has been around at least since the 1950s, introduced through beat and jazz culture.... also cites Scooby Doo (started 1969) : Shaggy: "Like, let's get out of here, Scoob!"*

Comment: Downvote! We have a stalker! This answer took some research, so let's see you do better.

Answer (score 1):

LOVE is a basic answer, even though I can only put it in 5 categories. They are:

1. Noun: **Love** grows old.
2. Verb: She **loves** him.
3. Adjective: The **love** birds have disappeared.
4. Pronoun: Give me the drink,**love**.
5. Interjection: **Love**! That all you need in life.

Answer (score 0):

Either this belongs in *English Language Learners* or the answer lies with Frank's tank, or both.

Frank was a soldier in charge of a very valuable radio set which sadly, he dropped off the back of a truck.

A moment later, a tank came round the corner and squashed the radio flat and what did Frank say, d’you suppose?

Fuck me; the fucking fucker’s fucking well fucked.

In any language, what word is anything remotely like so flexible?