# How many different parts of speech can the f-word be used as?

Tags: offensive-language, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis

In an "interesting" thread of comments we began to look at the word **fuck** in several different uses. Most of them were interjections and verb uses as would be expected.

But, perhaps dialectally, the word can easily be used as a noun, and even an adjective.

I would like to see how many different parts of speech can the word **fuck** be used as in its unmodified form. (*i.e.* no fucking, fucked, etc.).  Pluralization of noun or conjugation to fucks is the only acceptable variant.

The answer must provide real-world examples (*i.e.* no mere cramming of the word into a sentence and claiming it's an adverb!) And, I will even accept different verb types, adjectives, nouns, etc.  (e.g. If you can find a grammatical way to use it as a helper verb, my hat is off to you.)

If you wish to get extra credit, then you can answer with some of the variants above, but only after you have made an answer per the above rules.

The winner should have *both* the most varied and interesting answers!

**Just to make it clear, this is a word-game, and as such will be a bit broad or POB.**

Comment: How many parts of speech do you think there are? You may find a range of opinions in ELU.

Comment: @bib I'm not here to decide that. If you can show a distinct use and provide citations, that's worth extra to my mind.

Comment: As I mentioned to Joe, it's also problematic for this question that nouns can behave as modifiers, so there's really no way to make an “adjective” from fuck; a noun modifying another noun is a _noun adjunct_ rather than an adjective. You might think that's being fussy about definitions, but then definitions are at the heart of this puzzle. It'll be tough to come up with an answer that actually satisfies linguists and not just popular opinion.

Comment: As many as you got. How many is that?

Comment: And sorry if it seems that I'm being unnecessarily fussy or pedantic. I think it's an interesting question, just dangerously close to being primarily opinion based.

Comment: @BraddSzonye it is tagged word-game. I had the same thought, but figured a word-game had a wider latitude.

Comment: @BraddSzonye The no suffix rule *is* arbitrary. I did it to make the game harder!

Comment: Is it just in Australia that we have our own version of the [Buffalo sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)? [F*ck f*cking f*cked f*cker f*cking f*ckups f*ck f*cking f*cked f*cking f*ckup f*cking f*cker's f*ck] (http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Fuck_fucking_fucked_fucker_fucking_fuckups_fuck_fucking_fucked_fucking_fuckup_fucking_fucker%27s_fuck) means 'Gosh that very unpleasant drunk man who is frequently scammed by very incompetent people just ruined that incompetent copulating man's act of the horizontal tango'.

Comment: What part of speech is fuck in sweet fuck all?

Comment: @BraddSzonye Or how about Like fuck I will!  Is that the rare adverbial usage?  Or is it a noun phrase?

Comment: @long, or the more succinct: F*ck the f*cking f*ckers!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer is every part except articles and conjunctions.  Hmm, not sure about prepositions ...

Comment: @RBarryYoung [I got](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/155687/25030) a conjunction, stretching the term a bit, but still.

Comment: I really think that using `f*ck` on this post is stretching reasonable propriety to its breaking point. The whole post is about _fuck_ and its linguistic versatility, I think we should be allowed to write it. At the very least, it makes absurdly incomprehensible sentences like @long's example a bit easier to parse.

Comment: 20 or 30 years ago there was a tongue-in-cheek "scholarly" presentation (audio) played on the local radio station, giving examples of all the ways you could use this word. Of course, the actual word was bleeped out each time. See also _Army Creole_.

Comment: @PhilPerry it's likely the version linked to by Kristina below.

Comment: This page, with all comments expanded, has 117 instances of "fuck"

Comment: answer by video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_PkJ_4oEjc

Comment: See also [what word can fulfill the most parts of speech](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46277/what-word-can-fulfill-the-most-parts-of-speech).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Noun: ["Like fuck you will!."](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22it%20was%20fuck%20hard%22#hl=en&q=%22like%20fuck%20you%20will%22)

  - Also, since this is contested: *Hard as fuck* or  *Yes, thank you, I'd love a fuck*.
- Pronoun: "I hit fuck-face over there with a baseball bat." (both cheating *and* plagiarizing @Joe but you said nothing about hyphenated forms)
- Adjective: "He's fucked!"
- Verb: "I love to fuck while eating duck."
- Adverb:  ["It was fuck hard"](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22it%20was%20fuck%20hard%22), yes, apparently it is used by some.
- Conjunction: "I went swimming, fuck the cold." (as in, *I went swimming* despite *the cold*.)
- Preposition: don't think it's possible.
- Interjection: "Fuck! I was *sure* I could find a preposition!"

#### Extra brownie points (abandoning all pretense at seriousness):

- Auxiliary verb:

  - progressive aspect : *He fucking sleeping dude*!
  - epistemic modality : Wikipedia's [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb#A_list_of_auxiliaries_in_English) of *How dare you!* could be expressed in a single *Fuck!*.

Comment: That's not a conjunction, just an interjection.

Comment: Hyphenated is OK. It preserves the form well enough.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet fair enough. Will you let me get away with this one?

Comment: I'm asking from a genuine place of ignorance:  isn't *like fuck you will* an adverbial use of a noun?  Isn't *like fuck* modifying will?

Comment: @DavidM not too sure myself. I'd consider it a noun in the same way as _hell_ in _like hell you will_. I don't see why it's modifying the verb but mine is a place of considerable ignorance as well so I am open to corrections.

Comment: @terdon Hell and fuck are definitely nouns, but I think that they are part of a phrase that modifies the way you *will*. I did find [this](http://www.audioenglish.org/dictionary/like_hell.htm).

Comment: @DavidM I added a couple of examples that should be clearer.

Comment: I've found "It was fucking hard" to be more common than "It was fuck hard". (And as a construction, it's used quite frequently with a variety of verbs; "You'd better fucking run!" "I'll fucking tell you when I can come up with something else." etc.)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I would never use _it was fuck hard_ either, it sounds clumsy and non-native to my ear, that's why I linked to examples. I was not expecting to find any but some do seem to come from native speakers (though I cringe at the thought).

Comment: I would have said "fucking baseball bat."

Comment: @MichaelHampton no, _fucking_ has been forbidden by the OP.

Comment: You know, the word *pace* can be a preposition when used in sentences like “Nor, *pace* Mr. Smith, was I for one moment defending immorality in the journalist.” It originated as the ablative singular of Latin *pax* meaning peace, as in *pāce tuā*. But I feel like *fuck* could move into that sort of slot pretty slickly.  It would make a nice antonym to the preposition *pace*.

Comment: @tchrist huh, hadn't come across that usage, thanks. So in that context it means _with all due respect_, not sure how  well "Nor, _fuck_ Mr. Smith" would scan. Sounds too much like a continuation of "I will not marry Mr. Jones...".

Comment: Yes, that’s right: the OED says “Used chiefly as a courteous or ironical apology for a contradiction or difference of opinion.” So the *fuck Mr Smith* would be the opposite of “with all due respect”. Like I have no respect for those bozos. Which is kinda what it means anyway, fuck the authorities, and people will say what they will.

Comment: @tchrist I'd argue that it is still a verb. How is it different from _Well I'm going, and fuck the headmaster_?

Comment: You forgot "modal particle". As in: "Just fucking do it."

Comment: You, sir, are an artist!  I declare you the winner!  Please pick up your prize at the SE offices.

Comment: @TimSeguine true, but I did not want to give [Nike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_Do_It_(Nike)) free advertising.

Comment: Sorry to piss on the parade, but I have to call you on a couple. That's not a conjunction and that's not a pronoun. Or if they are then _every_ interjection I can think of could act like a conjunction. Likewise many nouns like a pronoun. Also, your adjective is not modifying a noun, it's a verbal past participle. Also... you can't think of 'fuck' used by itself as the plain primary verb from where this all came? We've all been entertained thoroughly; I humbly submit this in the interest of science.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that's absolutely horrible. It actually made me laugh out loud.

Comment: @Mitch Piss away! As I'm sure you know, this answer is very much tongue in cheek. Not sure I agree with your objections, mind you, but that is likely down to my own ignorance. I will object to the discrediting of my adjective though. It's modifying a noun, just like *fast* is in *he's fast*. It is a past participle but I submit that it's doing the job of an adjective there. Consider the difference between *he has been fucked* and *he is fucked*. It's as much an adjective as *finished*.

Comment: 1) it would be an adjective if you could say 'the fucked man'. That doesn't work for me (though it may for you). 2) we're talking about 'fuck' not 'fucked'. You definitely can't say 'the fuck man'

Comment: @Mitch awww! Dammit! I hadn't noticed that *fucked* was against the rules. And I've been basking in the glow of my answer for almost two years now! Fair point about *the fucked man*. It doesn't work for me either, I'll need to think about that.

Comment: @Mitch I agree with you about the conjunction. But I have to disagree about the participle: a participle can be said to be both adjective and verb at once, which I think is the only sensible way to classify it. The fact that it is not used attributively in this case doesn't mean it isn't an adjective: attributive use is only one aspect of adjectives. Cf. *able*, which cannot be used before a noun in its most frequent sense, but which is normally classified as an adjective.

Answer (score 10):

Here you go, the f-word used in all parts of speech, with a classical music background (this is a classic): http://youtu.be/7LZSUYoNPMs

The [transcript](http://lybio.net/tag/the-most-interesting-word-in-the-english-language-transcription/) in its entirety (sorry for all the f-bombs!):

> One of the most interesting words in the English language today is the word ‘fuck’. It is a magical word. Just by its sound it can describe, pain, pleasure, hate and love.
>   In language it falls into many grammatical categories. It can be used as a verb both transitive: “John fucked Mary” and intransitive: “Mary was fucked by John” and as a noun: “Mary is a fine Fuck”. It can be used as an adjective: “Mary is fucking beautiful”.
>   As you can see, there are not many words with the versatility of fuck. Besides the sexual meaning there are also the following uses.
>   Ignorance: Fucked if I know. Trouble: I guess I am fucked now! Fraud: I got fucked at the used car lot. Aggression: Fuck you! Displeasure: What the fuck is going on here? Difficulty: I can’t understand this fucking job! Incompetence: He is a fuck-off! Suspicion: What the fuck are you doing? Enjoyment: I had a fucking good time! Request: Get the fuck out of here! Hostility: I’m going to knock your fucking head off! Greeting: How the fuck are you? Apathy: Who gives a fuck. Innovation: Get a bigger fucking hammer. Surprise: Fuck! You scared the shit out of me. Anxiety: Today is really fucked.
>   [HiveFunnies] Source: LYBIO.net
>   And it is very healthy too! If every morning you do it as a transcendental meditation just when you get up first thing repeat the mantra: ‘Fuck you’ : five time. It clears your throat too!

Comment: Very funny!  But DISQUALIFIED!  Too many variants!  I'm looking for the *unmodified* f-word here!!!!

Comment: You have to admit, @DavidM, that variety is the spice of life and that most uses of the f-word in its unmodified form, short of "F*ck you!", "What the f*ck?", "He wants to f*ck", "She is a good f*ck", are cram-jobs, if you'll pardon the expression. :-)

Comment: Hahahahahahahahaha!  Plus one for the comment.

Comment: To see it done right, [check this out!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5lG-i2bjhk&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 7):

- Noun: "Fuck you, you **fuck.**"
- Pronoun: "I hit **fuck** over there with a baseball bat."
- Adjective: "And they leave a **fuck** stain on my couch."
- Verb: "They **fuck** all the time."
- Adverb: "She **fuck**(ing) screams so loud, I got a noise complaint."
- Conjunction: "I take Viagra, **fuck** I last all night."
- Preposition: "Come **fuck** me later."
- Interjection: "**Fuck!** I stubbed my toe."

Comment: Not buying the adverb Joe.  You know that should be "f*cking". :-)

Comment: Nice one with the pronoun, but that's not really a preposition (it's an infinitive verb), and the conjunction doesn't scan for me.

Comment: Also, that adjective smells more like a noun adjunct to me.

Comment: @KristinaLopez, I'm obviously trying to shoehorn it in, but I disagree; I think it qualifies the verb quite nicely. Using "f'ing screams" is more just a filler. As I'm sure we all know, a fuck scream is very different than a normal scream.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I think the preposition is close enough to "Come over later" for the example, but granted, it's a stretch. As to the adjective, "fuckstain" or "fuck-stain" would be a noun, but being literal, it does qualify the nature of the stain, thus I'm sticking with adjective.

Comment: ok, I'm withdrawing my comment... "f*ck scream" could work, but I'd be inclined to insert a hyphen.  ("She f*ck-screams so loud, I got a noise complaint.") :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez, fair enough on the withdrawal (rim-shot waiting to happen...) and possible hyphenation (I'd likely do that as well, but that's no fun for this exercise).

Comment: Nouns can modify other nouns; that's what a noun adjunct is. It's also problematic for David's question in general, because using _fuck_ as a modifier doesn't really make it an adjective.

Comment: But since noun adjuncts function as adjectives, ipso facto, doesn't that conform to the rules of the game?

Comment: Your preposition is actually a proposition, not the same thing!

Comment: That preposition is more than just a stretch—it's nonsensical. It would, if it made sense, make for a great possible fuckquences (like sequences, but fucktual): “The fuck you fucking fuck, fuck?” (In real English: “What the fuck are you fucking with, you fuck?”)

Answer (score 2):

An important contribution to research on **fuck** is the classic article by Quang, [English sentences without overt grammatical subject](http://babel.ucsc.edu/~hank/quangphucdong.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6D7rWLzloOI) where the versatility of the word *Fuck* is explained.

**Transcript**

> Osho used this sketch on the word fuck first in a talk in 1980 and repeated it again in this later talk. We have seen the original of this sketch being attributed to Jack Wagner, George Carlin and Monty Python - no one seems to be sure.
>
> "When Friedrich Nietzsche declared, "God is dead," he himself became utterly helpless no consolation, no hope, no meaning. He had to go through a long process of insanity.
>
> Nietzsche seems to me to be the most important figure that has dominated the world in this century. Without any argument his statement has infiltrated into every mind. But he was not aware of the implications. I have no problem if God is dead. There is no need to mourn his death.
>
> The problem is that if God is dead, then you lose the most important word in your language and you will need a substitute. God was one end, one extreme, and when one extreme disappears from your mental vision, the necessary and inevitable is that you will fall to the other extreme.
>
> And that's what has happened, Milarepa. Instead of God, `fuck' has become the most important word in our language. Even if Friedrich Nietzsche comes back, he will be surprised and he will try to resurrect somehow the dead God, because this is stupid. But you will need a whole report on it, a whole research.
>
> One of the most interesting words in the English language today is the word `fuck'. It is a magical word. Just by its sound it can describe pain, pleasure, hate and love. In language it falls into many grammatical categories. It can be used as a verb, both transitive, "John fucked Mary," and intransitive, "Mary was fucked by John", and as a noun, "Mary is a fine fuck." It can be used as an adjective, "Mary is fucking beautiful."
>      As you can see, there are not many words with the versatility of fuck. Besides the sexual meaning, there are also the following uses:
>
> • Ignorance: Fucked if I know.
>   • Trouble: I guess I am fucked now!
>   • Fraud: I got fucked at the used car lot.
>   • Aggression: Fuck you!
>   • Displeasure: What the fuck is going on here?
>   • Difficulty: I can't understand this fucking job.
>   • Incompetence: He is a fuck-off.
>   • Suspicion: What the fuck are you doing?
>   • Enjoyment: I had a fucking good time.
>   • Request: Get the fuck out of here.
>   • Hostility: I'm going to knock your fucking head off.
>   • Greeting: How the fuck are you?
>   • Apathy: Who gives a fuck?
>   • Innovation: Get a bigger fucking hammer.
>   • Surprise: Fuck! You scared the shit out of me!
>   • Anxiety: Today is really fucked.
>
> And it is very healthy if every morning you do it as a transcendental meditation just when you get up, first thing, repeat the mantra "fuck you" five times; it clears your throat too!

Comment: Funny, but I was looking for description of the actual parts of speech, not the mere usage.

Comment: This not only doesn't answer the question, it's also the exact same transcript, bar the irrelevant background on Osho and Nietzsche as @Kristina's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

A friend on our sister site [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) @MBraedley suggested this gem, but he didn't post it as I had hoped:

[Use of the F-word in Canada](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=E5lG-i2bjhk&feature=youtu.be).

Though many of the references are over my head as being too Canada specific, this is a brilliant piece of artistry!