# A great use of the f-word

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Can someone analyse this sentence for me please? I heard a trucker say this, in the workshop, when we told him the starter motor on his truck was knackered.  To our amusement he said:

> "Fuck, the fucking fucker's fucked!"

I reckon it's a pretty good effort, being a 5 word sentence with only one word that is not the f-word.

Unfortunately, I was not taught the framework of English in the 70s New Zealand school system.  I know what adjectives and nouns are, and that's about it.

Comment: The f-word can be used as an exclamation, a verb, an adjective, and a noun.

Comment: INTERJECTION, the ADJECTIVE NOUN'[COPULA] PARTICIPLE-ADJECTIVE.

Comment: @RobustosupportsUkraine why not make your comment the answer? It is clearly the simple analytical answer and it seems ungenerous for anyone now to repeat it as their own answer.

Comment: [Relevant question](/questions/155664/)

Comment: @Anton: OK, if you insist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many different parts of speech can the f-word be used as?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155664/how-many-different-parts-of-speech-can-the-f-word-be-used-as)

Comment: "Great use of the f-word"? Why? Fuck is a precise English word for the Latinate "copulation", and its use as a mindless swear word has resulted in the absurd situation where publications will print it as a swear word, but not if it is used literally as a verb or noun, where they insert asterisks or replace it with euphemisms like "bonk". No shit! — either. That comes out as infantile "poo".

Comment: The duplicate is a delight to read but as a list of usages it does not formally  answer the question, so I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 5):

The whole sentence may be considered as an *intensifier*, which it does by turning every normal part of speech into one of those.

Each of these intensifiers substitutes for a normal word. Consider:

> Fuck, (interjection)
> the fucking (adjective)
> fucker's (noun + copula)
> fucked! (participle-adjective)

If you were to write this sentence without the severe profanity, it would read something like this:

> Damn, the stupid truck is broken!

It could also be rendered as a scream of anguish or consternation:

> Aaaaaaaarrrrrrrrgh!

Comment: Abso-f-word-lutely.